# Invalid Object Name - Table Names Getting Concatenated - Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have the following Join column defined in my `User` Entity object

```
@Entity(name = "User")
public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_Id")
    private long userId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = LookupOrder.class)
    Map<Long, String> orderMap = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Order_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private LookupOrder lookupOrder;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Order.java

```
@Entity(name = "Lookup_Order")
public class LookupOrder{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Order_Id")
    private long orderId;

    @Column(name = "Order_Num")
    private String orderNum;

    //getters & setters
}
```

And attempt to retrieve a User with the following Spring Repository method inside of a `@RequestMapping` method

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getUserById(@PathVariable(value="id") Long id,  Model model) {
    User user = userRepo.findOne(id);
    //do stuff
}
```

However my Table Names seem to get concatenated and throw and return an SQLException:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'User_Lookup_Order'.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this or why the Object is translated this way?

**UPDATE**: The program actually fails when creating the delete SQL query

```
2015-09-01 14:49:30.808 DEBUG 6868 --- [    http-8080-2] o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister      : Deleting collection: [com.myapp.entities.User.orderMap#2]
2015-09-01 14:49:30.881 DEBUG 6868 --- [    http-8080-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from User_Lookup_Order where User_User_Id=?
2015-09-01 14:49:31.026 DEBUG 6868 --- [    http-8080-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : could not execute statement [n/a]

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'User_Lookup_Order'.
```

Comment: What table has the other table's key as foreign key?

Comment: `User` has `Look_Order`'s PK as a Foreign Key

Comment: Included the @JoinColumn

Comment: I'm just wild guessing, but can you try adding the `referencedColumnName` attribute, such as: `@JoinColumn(name = "Order_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "User_Id")` (as I said, this is wild guessing, maybe this is not needed).

Comment: Can you turn on DEBUG logging and paste the generated SQL that is failing?

Comment: Are you using postgres? Use a @joinTable on your onetomany to rename the table if you want

Comment: Here's the generated SQL - `Static select for collection com.myapp.entities.User.orderMap: select orderMap0_.User_User_Id ... from User_Lookup_Order inner join Lookup_Order on ...
` and I'm using SQLServer

Comment: @acdcjunior including the `referencedColumnName` returned the same results